# Iframe transparency issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have iframes to represent the pull-down menu.  Problem is that when the iframe is displayed, I can see the content from the parent page.

Is there a way not to make an iframe transparent?

```
jQuery('<iframe id="accountframe" style="position: absolute; width: 290px; height:     140px;  margin-top: 0px;  margin-left: 0px; top:0px; left:0px; text-align:left overflow:hidden; allowTransparency:false"  src="test.jsp" ></iframe>').appendTo('#account');
```

I'm using jQuery to dynamically add/remove the iframe.  I already tried allowTransparency:false as a style sheet and also allowTransparency="false" as an attribute, but both ways is not working.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about `allowTransparency="true"` ?
Since you *do* want it to be transparent?

It would also help to set `background-color:transparent` on the iframe, and to make sure that the page you load into the iframe does not define a background color in its body.

Answer (score 0):

There is some mistake in your code:
`allowTransparency` is not a CSS property. The `allowtransparency` is a attribute on the iframe element. And you write allowTransparency as a CSS property.

Try with this code -

```
jQuery('<iframe id="accountframe" style="position: absolute; width: 290px; height:140px; margin-top: 0px; margin-left: 0px; top:0px; left:0px; text-align:left overflow:hidden;" allowTransparency="false" src="test.jsp" ></iframe>').appendTo('#account');
```

[There is article for this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms533072%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

As you mention you also try `allowTransparency="false"` as an attribute, but if you want to make your `IFrame` transparent. You need to set `allowTransparency="true"` on Iframe.

Be sure both the `IFRAME` and its source `BODY` element have a `background:transparent` style rule applied:

```
<iframe frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" style="background:transparent" ... ></iframe>
```

and in the source:

```
<body style="background:transparent">
```

PS: CSS styles above are inline just for example.

Try This:

```
jQuery('<iframe id="accountframe" style="position: absolute; width: 290px; height:140px; margin-top: 0px; margin-left: 0px; top:0px; left:0px; text-align:left overflow:hidden;" allowTransparency="true" src="test.jsp" ></iframe>').appendTo('#account');
```